# Using Distinct with Specific Case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table which has records like this:

```
    NAME    AE  BYTES_ALLOC MAXBYTES
---------------------------------------------------------
    SYSTEM  NO  10805575680 10805575680
    SYSTEM  YES 2147483648  10737418240
    CTXD    NO  52428800    52428800
    SYSAUX  YES 7228882944  10737418240
    OLAP    NO  104857600   104857600
    OWAPUB  NO  11534336    11534336
    AKTAR   NO  4294967296  4294967296
    PORTAL  NO  106954752   106954752
    TBS     NO  1073741824  1073741824
    ODM     NO  104857600   104857600
```

I want only one "name"(unique) value on the rows, and if there is `yes` and `no` values in `ae` column for value in `name` column. As you can see there is two "system" values on the rows. What i want is to sum both `bytes_alloc` and `maxbytes` values and make its `ae` value as `yes`. Something like below:

```
    NAME    AE  BYTES_ALLOC MAXBYTES
---------------------------------------------------------
    SYSTEM  YES 12747483648  10737418240
    CTXD    NO  52428800    52428800
    SYSAUX  YES 7228882944  10737418240
    OLAP    NO  104857600   104857600
    OWAPUB  NO  11534336    11534336
    AKTAR   NO  4294967296  4294967296
    PORTAL  NO  106954752   106954752
    TBS     NO  1073741824  1073741824
    ODM     NO  104857600   104857600
```

Comment: You want to sum the `MAXBYTES` column or not? Your sample is different from what you say...

Comment: i want to sum maxbytes . also i want to sum bytes_alloc.

Comment: OK, please check my answer and let me know if it's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select name, ae, bytes_alloc, maxbytes  from 
(select name, 
 max (ae) over (partition by name order by name) ae, 
 sum(bytes_alloc) over (partition by name order by name) bytes_alloc,
 sum(maxbytes) over (partition by name order by name) maxbytes,
 row_number() over (partition by name order by name) rn
 from tbl) s
 where s.rn = 1
```

Comment: That worked perfect. May i ask you about partition? What does it do?

Comment: `Partition`, as the name suggests, partitions the dataset into subsets based on the columns you specify. It then performs the operations specified on each of these subsets.

Answer (score 2):

Because `YES` is "greater than" `NO`, you can use `MAX()`:

```
SELECT NAME, MAX(AE) AE, SUM(BYTES_ALLOC) BYTES_ALLOC, SUM(MAXBYTES) MAXBYTES
FTOM TABLE
GROUP BY NAME,
```